# Method causing a weird crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, crash-reports

I am building this app and I am encountering some issues I haven't seen before.

1. the app crashes when I run the method below which is connected to a `UIButton` for a trigger. so when I hit the button it does the print and then the simulator crashes to the springboard. if I launch the app again from the springboard it doesn't get to the print method, if I rebuild from Xcode it does, and then promptly crashes as before.
2. Usually there is some info in the debug console where I can at least get a clue as to what is going on but there doesn't seem to be much there. One thing I noticed is that there is something about accessibility being turned on or something when the app initially launches in the simulator, I can't remember if that is always there or not:

> 2010-02-18 10:35:19.024 Cash[497:207]
>   ******* Accessibility Status Changed: On 2010-02-18 10:35:19.134
>   Cash[497:207] ********** Loading AX
>   for: com.yourcompany.Cash ************
>
> copyright 2010 Nicholas Iannone:

```
-(IBAction) logTransaction {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
indexPath = [self.categoryTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

NSInteger selectedCategory = indexPath.row;
[indexPath release];
NSString *categoryString = [[NSString alloc] init];
categoryString = [self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:selectedCategory];
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000.0f;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
double x = 10.0;
double y = 10.0;
NSString *descriptionString = [[NSString alloc] init];

descriptionString = descriptionField.text;
//[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

Transaction *newTransaction = [[Transaction alloc] initWithAmount:    [self.amountField.text integerValue] 
                                                      description: descriptionString 
                                                         category: categoryString   
                                                        locationX: x 
                                                        locationY: y];

                                      [categoryString release];
[newTransaction print];

 //log transaction here...

[newTransaction release];
```

**here's the console output:**

> 2/18/10 10:35:19
>   AM    Cash[497]   ********** Loading AX
>   for: com.yourcompany.Cash ************
>   2/18/10 10:35:28
>   AM    Cash[497]   0.000000,sddssd,Snacks,2010-02-18
>   10:35:28 -0800,10.000000,10.000000
>   2/18/10 10:35:28
>   AM    com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[91]   (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.Cash[0x9148][497])
>   Job appears to have crashed:
>   Segmentation fault 2/18/10 10:35:28
>   AM    SpringBoard[482]    Application 'Cash'
>   exited abnormally with signal 11:
>   Segmentation fault 2/18/10 10:35:28
>   AM    ReportCrash[491]    Saved crash report
>   for Cash[497] version ??? (???) to
>   /Users/knyck2/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Cash_2010-02-18-103528_Nicholas-Iannones-MacBook-Pro.crash

**here's the crash log:**

> Process:         Cash [497] Path:
>   /Users/knyck2/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/3.2/Applications/F54FA00C-9E77-4B9A-8774-2D5B5488A1BA/Cash.app/Cash
>   Identifier:      Cash Version:
>   ??? (???) Code Type:       X86
>   (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [91]
>
> Date/Time:       2010-02-18
>   10:35:28.631 -0800 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.6.2 (10C540) Report
>   Version:  6
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at
>   0x0000000014600478 Crashed Thread:  0 
>   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   objc_msgSend() selector name: release
>   iPhone Simulator 3.2 (193), iPhone OS
>   3.2 (7B298g)
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x9805aedb objc_msgSend + 27 1
>   UIKit
>     0x002b4a19 _UIApplicationHandleEvent
>   + 8468 2   GraphicsServices               0x02f1f2a8 PurpleEventCallback + 1576
>   3   CoreFoundation
>     0x026bb87e CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   4094 4   CoreFoundation
>     0x026ba878 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 88 5 
>   GraphicsServices
>     0x02f1da4d GSEventRunModal + 217 6
>   GraphicsServices
>     0x02f1db12 GSEventRun + 115 7   UIKit
>     0x002b265d UIApplicationMain + 1134 8
>   Cash
>     0x00002648 main + 102 (main.m:13) 9
>   Cash
>     0x000025b6 start + 54
>
> Thread 1: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x937b88da mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x937b9047 mach_msg + 68 2
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x026bb022 CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   1954 3   CoreFoundation
>     0x026ba878 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 88 4 
>   WebCore
>     0x03151933 RunWebThread(void*) + 467
>   5   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x937e5fbd _pthread_start + 345 6
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x937e5e42 thread_start + 34
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State
>   (32-bit):   eax: 0x07802a50  ebx:
>   0x00017711  ecx: 0x9655d0c4  edx:
>   0x07833ba2   edi: 0x14600478  esi:
>   0x00000000  ebp: 0xbfffe158  esp:
>   0xbfffdfd4    ss: 0x0000001f  efl:
>   0x00010206  eip: 0x9805aedb   cs:
>   0x00000017    ds: 0x0000001f   es:
>   0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs:
>   0x00000037   cr2: 0x14600478
>
> Binary Images:
>       0x1000 -     0x5ff7 +Cash ??? (???)
>   
>   /Users/knyck2/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/3.2/Applications/F54FA00C-9E77-4B9A-8774-2D5B5488A1BA/Cash.app/Cash
>       0xd000 -     0xfff7 +PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib ??? (???)
>   <8C448816-8655-143E-DA39-C8157FDA8C8B>
>   /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib
>   0x14000 -   0x1a8ff3 +Foundation ???
>   (???)
>   <4361202B-C361-85C9-AAD0-3D062EF44941>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
>   0x29e000 -  0x2063fe7 +UIKit ??? (???)
>   <524597DC-F210-115D-E31D-01A3429E25C7>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>   0x23be000 -  0x25c6fe7 
>   com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.359.16 (???)
>   <017CBE03-17D3-25FD-E775-087B415993AA>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x262e000 -  0x2665ff7 +CoreLocation
>   ??? (???)
>   <80CA49D0-A8EA-0638-A407-0CC131AEEB41>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
>   0x268e000 -  0x2799fff +CoreFoundation
>   ??? (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   0x287d000 -  0x2a15fe7
>   +libicucore.A.dylib ??? (???) <13A09086-26EF-E491-ADD8-9019C31542FC>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
>   0x2a76000 -  0x2b75fe7
>   +libxml2.2.dylib ??? (???) <78BEDCC4-E0FD-1C59-70ED-46FB3D76055C>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
>   0x2b9a000 -  0x2c41fe7 +CFNetwork ???
>   (???)
>   <24AFEAF9-230F-C79A-3A2F-BB9F1945CF9A>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
>   0x2cc0000 -  0x2cf4ff7
>   +SystemConfiguration ??? (???) <5448E217-DB17-F241-AB84-C2FE18372948>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
>   0x2d16000 -  0x2d65ff7 +Security ???
>   (???)
>   <90BF3878-B2F5-8FD0-4E81-B59E64C47E1D>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
>   0x2d8b000 -  0x2e58fe7
>   +libsqlite3.dylib ??? (???) <3B663A82-D85F-3CD5-130C-FAA6C5ED2D0E>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x2e68000 -  0x2ef3fff 
>   com.apple.framework.IOKit 1.5.1 (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
>   0x2f19000 -  0x2f26ff3
>   +GraphicsServices ??? (???) <7FB2250F-CDD1-D975-0387-6E884CC061CD>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
>   0x2f39000 -  0x3071ff7 +JavaScriptCore
>   ??? (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
>   0x30c5000 -  0x3888fe7 +WebCore ???
>   (???)
>   <8801B91D-C8BC-51CC-B80A-FB9C67BA8FF2>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
>   0x3db5000 -  0x3e4bff7 +WebKit ???
>   (???)
>   <0D579ECA-E22E-7C70-A214-73D2221CD1C7>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
>   0x3ec9000 -  0x3f87fe7 +ImageIO ???
>   (???)
>   <524C2CFC-6F77-3B4F-390F-40711BB56980>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
>   0x3fb2000 -  0x3fd0ff7 +AddressBook
>   ??? (???)
>   <2EF304E3-4B16-5B0E-E072-BFABF4B44CF5>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
>   0x3ff1000 -  0x4145fe7 +AudioToolbox
>   ??? (???)
>   <27DC788A-231B-9DB5-0B48-04A2A8D27F32>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
>   0x4198000 -  0x425aff7 +QuartzCore ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
>   0x42b5000 -  0x42c2ff7
>   +SpringBoardServices ??? (???) <3CDBCAE3-B6D3-D734-6CB0-AB39EBBE7D57>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
>   0x42cd000 -  0x42f9fff +AppSupport ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
>   0x4319000 -  0x435cfe7 +CoreText ???
>   (???)
>   <971632EA-E809-8D15-BE25-E115A4FBDFF4>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
>   0x438c000 -  0x43c7ff7
>   +MobileCoreServices ??? (???) <5BFA76AC-EC1B-8D9F-4533-B3DD44041107>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
>   0x43e5000 -  0x448efe7 +ProofReader
>   ??? (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
>   0x44ab000 -  0x44b6ff7 +CoreVideo ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
>   0x44c2000 -  0x44d8fe7 +OpenGLES ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
>   0x44e2000 -  0x4558ff3 +CoreAudio ???
>   (???)
>   <14C17E9E-0D13-A7BD-3A06-C3F460FD261C>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
>   0x4594000 -  0x4649fe7 
>   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???)
>   <39CDB041-9DF5-01B1-4B33-03EC4CCA40B3>
>   /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib 
>   0x468f000 -  0x46b5fff 
>   libssl.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???)
>   <924E1BF8-C24D-4A5C-3DB6-A85034392D19>
>   /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib  0x46ea000
>   -  0x46eaff7 +AccessibilitySettingsLoader ??? (???) <21BFF58D-21D2-210F-3150-873A8CC87399>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
>   0x46ef000 -  0x46f1ff7
>   +libAccessibility.dylib ??? (???) <9F1CEAA6-2910-7F97-A626-DAA33724ED79>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib  0x7900000 -  0x7909ffb +IAP ??? (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
>   0x7916000 -  0x794cff7 +UIKit ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/UIKit.axbundle/UIKit
>   0x7990000 -  0x799bff7
>   +UIAccessibility ??? (???) <4E2BD72C-F67F-D0DF-78FA-FB1D5840F6B7>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIAccessibility.framework/UIAccessibility
>   0x79ab000 -  0x79baff7 +AXRuntime ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AXRuntime.framework/AXRuntime
>   0x79c8000 -  0x7a0afe7
>   +libCGFreetype.A.dylib ??? (???) <8853F0B7-8EE5-AD36-BC97-B0AD8782E547>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
>   0x7f31000 -  0x7f57fe7 +libRIP.A.dylib
>   ??? (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
>   0x9cff000 -  0x9d3efe7 +TextInput ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
>   0x9d6a000 -  0x9eafff3
>   +libmecabra.dylib ??? (???) <1C45F15E-3F66-3F28-46C7-78EC4B63C803>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
>   0x9ee1000 -  0x9ff4ff7 +CoreData ???
>   (???)
>   <6F49CC28-8102-D224-EBBD-12045B6DBA92>
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
>   0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4162b  dyld 132.1
>   (???)
>   <211AF0DD-42D9-79C8-BB6A-1F4BEEF4B4AB>
>   /usr/lib/dyld 0x91fe7000 - 0x91feafe7 
>   libmathCommon.A.dylib ??? (???)
>   <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E>
>   /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
>   0x93497000 - 0x93501fe7 
>   libstdc++.6.dylib ??? (???)
>   <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213>
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib 0x937b8000
>   - 0x9395cfeb  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???)
>   
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x96692000
>   - 0x966d8ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <85670A64-3B67-8162-D441-D8E0BE15CA94>
>   /usr/lib/libauto.dylib 0x9706e000 -
>   0x97082fe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???)
>   <14CB053A-7C47-96DA-E415-0906BA1B78C9>
>   /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib 0x98055000 -
>   0x98102fe7  libobjc.A.dylib ??? (???)
>   
>   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x98103000 -
>   0x981f7fe7  libiconv.2.dylib ??? (???)
>   <0C578460-3929-29DD-585A-DB1E0C977425>
>   /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 0x98fd9000 -
>   0x98fe7fe7  libz.1.dylib ??? (???)
>   <7B7A02AB-DA99-6180-880E-D28E4F9AA8EB>
>   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib 0xffff0000 -
>   0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ???
>   (???)
>   
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: thanks for reformatting dirk!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
indexPath = [self.categoryTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

NSInteger selectedCategory = indexPath.row;
[indexPath release];
```

You're instantiating an empty NSIndexPath and then overwriting the reference to it. The release on the last line is sent to an entirely different object returned by the table view. The object you create is never used and never released.

This will work:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.categoryTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSInteger selectedCategory = indexPath.row;
```

You're not creating an NSIndexPath object, so you have no responsibility to release it.

(your unnecessary release is causing the index path instance to be prematurely deallocated. When Apple's code tries to release the object, it no longer exists, and the app crashes)

Comment: thanks man, that worked a treat. i had a hell of a time trying to figure that thing out and it surprisingly worked, the first time you tried it at least, but yeah it was broken. thanks a lot the code seems to be putting along perfectly now thanks to both answers here, i wish I could give two answers the green check but only one allowed. 

Now im off to try and solve more problems.

:)

Comment: Thanks. I was getting a crash after releasing text from returned by NSXMLParser. My question is, isn't the index path returned by the a new object? Doesn't it increase the reference count when it's returned by the method?

Comment: @JackBeNimble the returned indexPath was created by something else. you don’t manage other object’s things. Only release objects you alloc+init

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, as not all of the code is there. In your init method for the Transaction class, do you make sure to retain the strings? (category and description).

The thing that stands out to me is that you initialize the Transaction, then release the categoryString immediately after. If you're not retaining the string, then this could be the source of your crash.

On a side note, you are leaking memory. Here:

```
NSString *descriptionString = [[NSString alloc] init];
descriptionString = descriptionField.text;
```

descriptionString is pointing to a newly allocating string, only to be reassigned to an existing string, so the first string is leaked. You should change this to:

```
NSString *descriptionString;
descriptionString = descriptionField.text;
```

or more simply:

```
NSString *descriptionString = descriptionField.text;
```

Comment: i have the strings set up as different properties and I'm using copy, maybe I should use retain?

     @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;

as far as the memory leak, thanks, I have been messing with releases because in researching this I saw that a segmentation a fault may be caused by over releasing an object.

trying a retain now

Comment: I think that solved the issue although the program still is not working quite right but I think that was it. thanks

Comment: the property declarations only effect the getters and setters, not the init function, so the problem could have still existed if you didn't use the setter function in your init method. Glad my solution helped.

Comment: i was using the setter in the init method